# Box characters within JSON response

Tags: java, javascript, json

This is my JSON String which is generated using Java:

```
[{\"userFirstNm\":\"Tamás\",\"userAsscId\":\"37732\",\"userLastNm\":\"Török\",\"userLanId\":\"a37732\"}]
```

Using an alert in JavaScript displays boxes inside string and breaks my `eval` function.

Please find details in attached screen shot.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/336da972f3.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/336da972f3.png)

Comment: It looks like your string has double-escape characters in it (`\\"`).  This would explain why `\"` shows in the alert dialog.

Comment: Well, It should not have escape characters at all...

Comment: Make sure you have the character encoding of the page set correctly.

Comment: you are right there is issue content type in Controller.

pResponse.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
  pResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
  pResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "No-Cache");
  pResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache,no-store,max-age=0");
  pResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 1);

Answer (score 1):

its invalid json

try this.

```
[{"userFirstNm":"Tamás","userAsscId":"37732","userLastNm":"Török","userLanId":"a37732"}]
```